# How to implement an implicit rule which depends on a similarly named file in GNU Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If I want to create `foo.txt` when the user runs `make foo`, that's simple enough:

```
foo: foo.txt

foo.txt:
    touch foo.txt
```

But what if I don't know about the name `foo` ahead of time, and I want to support creating any other arbitrarily named text file?

Here's what I tried:

```
%: %.txt

%.txt:
    touch %.txt
```

But if I try `make clojure`, instead of running `touch clojure.txt`, it fails with `No rule to make target clojure`.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong here.  First, your recipe is wrong; `%` in a recipe is not special to make and won't be replaced.  Your command `touch %.txt` creates the file literally named `%.txt` regardless of what the pattern matches.  You want to use `touch $@` here; see discussion of [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).

Second, your rule:

```
%: %.txt
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  Unlike explicit rules, creating an implicit or pattern rule with no recipe does not simply create a prerequisite relationship for a target that matches the pattern: instead it [deletes a pre-existing pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).

Since you have no pre-existing pattern rule, your makefile is identical to writing simply:

```
%.txt:
        touch %.txt
```

and there's no way to build a target `clojure` with this makefile.

One solution is to create a dummy recipe like this:

```
% : %.txt
        @:

%.txt:
        touch $@
```

Another solution, if you had no other targets you wanted to add to your makefile, would be to use a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html) to tell make that every target should be considered this type:

```
$(MAKECMDGOALS): % : %.txt

%.txt:
         touch $@
```

The [`MAKECMDGOALS` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html) contains whatever targets you provided on the command line to make.